# How to read a file in resources folder as an InputStream in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have the following directory structure.

```
- main
-- scala
-- resources
--- file.json
```

I want to read `file.json` *as a java.io.InputStream*. I know I can read it as a `Source` but I don't know how to get an `InputStream`.

Comment: Of course I know this. I want to read file from resources and not local path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the following way.

`getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName)`

Answer (score 0):

You answered while I was writing my answer:

I propose this solution:

```
  def readJsonWithTry(filePath: String): Try[InputStream] = {
    Try {
      val lines = getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(filePath)
      lines
      }
  }

  readJsonWithTry("resourceName") match {
    case Success(s) => s
    case Failure(f) => println(s"Failed, message is: $f")
  }
```